# Remote MySQL connection using php not working

Tags: php, mysql

I can connect to the remote MySQL database from the MySQL Workbench using these credentials but when I try to connect using the php script I keep getting a connection timed out error. The MySQL server has its bind address already changed, it is running on a Linode server so I am not sure if that changes anything.

I'm using the php connect test script for MySQLi from W3 Schools.

```
<?php
$servername = "remote-db-IP";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

The exact error I get is

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in
>   /home/glavxfrw/public_html/db-connect-test2.php on line 7 Connection
>   failed: Connection timed out

Comment: How do you connect to the database ? can you provide the code you use ?

Comment: Um... "what" php?

Comment: Seeing your edit now: simple, you didn't choose a database.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- the database parameter is not required, you can connect to a mysql server without selecting a DB http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: I've tried with a database selected but that doesn't even seem to return an error, the database name is ResApp and i can connect to it in the MySQL Workbench but not through the php test script.

Comment: so see if error reporting throws anything back

Comment: @Crozet fair enough.

Comment: all it states is connection error connection timed out.

Comment: @DVNT btw, you sure your host allows for a remote connection? Your server uses an IP address; did you try `localhost` instead?

Comment: @Fred-ii- would I use localhost even though they are on separate machines? I worry since the website I am trying to connect from has its own phpmyadmin set up that it might try to get data from those databases as oppose to the remote ones.

Comment: @DVNT some hosted servers require `localhost` as a few of mine do. I'd check with your host (if hosted) as to what settings you need to use. If you're trying execute this from your own pc and it does not allow for remote connections, then that could be if. And "how" you're using this file could also be an issue. Are you using it from your machine and is it in fact `http://localhost/file.php` or directly in your browser as `file:///`? I know I seem to be picking at straws here, but those are the questions that come to mind. Again; see if error reporting throws back anything and check your logs.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sorry if I caused any confusion but my remote Database is hosted on a Linode server and I am trying to connect from a website being hostd on a different server, that is where I am running this php script. I am trying to connect this website with the remote database, not my personal computer, since I can connect to the remote database perfectly fine through the MySQL workbench application.

Comment: The code is fine, its to do with your iptables / firewall rules that are preventing you to connect remotely

Comment: @MaciejCygan im able to connect through the MySQL workbench though, would I still be able to do that even with the firewall rules and iptables effecting it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out on hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051976/mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-connection-timed-out-on-hosting)