# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out on hosting

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I am trying to connect mysql database using php. But it is running fine on local machine but not when hosted online and error appeared as 
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('sql6.freesqldatabase.com','user_name','password','database_name');
if(mysqli_connect_error())
    die("couldn't connect to database");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your MySQL server is probably not configured to accept requests from the host you're trying to access it from.

Check the configuration for the server.
Since you say the local machine can access it check where you permitted this and do the same for the ip of the online host.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, AWS firewall was blocking my web server.

> **Adding the web servers IP address to the firewall exceptions fixed
>   this for me.**

Answer (score 1):

There might firewall in the host which is blocking the request to MySQL server. In my case adding the firewall rule helped me out.

**Ubuntu**

To allow one device to access the MySQL server,

```
sudo ufw allow from remote_IP_address to any port 3306
```

To allow any device to connect to MySQL server,

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

If your website and MySQL database are hosted on separate servers, make sure that you've mentioned correct MySQL hostname (resolvable) in connection string.

In case you've specified the correct username, most probably your MySQL server isn't allowing remote MySQL connections from web server where you site resides. 
Contact your web hosting provider for the exact MySQL hostname and to allow your web server IP address for remote MySQL connections.

Comment: If MySQL server is not allowing remote connections then how I am able to connect to server on my local machine

Comment: Are you able to connect to Remote MySQL server from your local computer via website? If yes, then your web server is not allowed to connect to MySQL server. Typically, remote MySQL is a security risk and not allowed to get connected for all hosts (% argument). First thing to ensure is, web server and MySQL server can communicate over TCP IP 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to white list your hosting server's ip address to your DB server.

So your DB server will accept requests from your hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the port (3306?) to the connection string as well.