# AWS RDS DB slow when deployed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I'm trying to implement a CMS on AWS using mostly free tier services and am doing so using PHP, and have already implemented this using PHPMyAdmin in school.

**The problem:**

---

I wanted to do this using RDS, but I've come up with a pretty strange issue.

When I upload my site to Elastic Beanstalk and try to connect to the DB from there, I face incredibly long wait times. Sometimes it returns error 504 from long wait times.

This is not an issue with the Database's speed, however. I know this because ***I can run this code on localhost and it works exactly as intended*** (see photo)

[image: Speed on localhost]

Only half a second to load!

**What I think is happening:**

---

Something must be going on while it's being executed in Elastic Beanstalk. I don't know quite what, but it's taking way too long.

**Extra info:**

---

I connect to the DB using the following code (credentials are spoofed):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("mydb.cebelvm3fa0n.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com","USERNAME","PASSWORD","mydb");
```

Both my database and EL instance are run from ca-central. The connection is not failing, it is taking an extreme amount of time.

the page that is failing is http://howardpearce.ca/posts.php

If you have any ideas on what it could be, I would appreciate it very much. Thanks!

NOTE:

> I will post certain bits of my code, but creating an MCVE is really
>   not feasible as I would have to give my DB password, and you would
>   need to re-create my AWS environment, so please don't ask for one, I
>   can always give more detail.

Comment: Have you checked the elastic beanstalk logs? On the logging part of the web console you can request the last 100 lines of logs. They might have some clues in them. Also, does it actually succeed sometimes? I.e. are you sure it's not a firewall issue?

Comment: It has succeeded previously, but that was when it loaded the DB on every page. It times out now because on posts it's also trying some select queries along with connecting. I'll check out the logs, thanks!

Comment: I checked the logs, and most notably got the error `PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /var/app/current/posts.php on line 3
` , which when searched leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051976/mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-connection-timed-out-on-hosting

Comment: I see now... I don't have a security group allowing connections from the server. Will get on that now, if this fixes it I'll post an answer.

Comment: Just an FYI for those new to AWS, if you have different servers for your DB and your application, you reap lower latency benefits from deploying the servers in the same Placement Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @colde mentioned checking logs, I quickly found an error code which lead me to the right resources.

My database was only configured to allow connections from my IP, and the firewall was blocking out my Elastic Beanstalk instance, I just had to add a new security rule.

Thanks!